# How to read orc data source in spark structured streaming?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to read orc stream in java :

Dataset d2 = sparkSession.readStream().format("orc").option("path","file:///Users/rahulkumar/work/structuredstreaming/maporc/").load();

which throws the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Schema must be specified when creating a streaming source DataFrame. If some files already exist in the directory, then depending on the file format you may be able to create a static DataFrame on that directory with 'spark.read.load(directory)' and infer schema from it.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.sourceSchema(DataSource.scala:222)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.sourceInfo$lzycompute(DataSource.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.sourceInfo(DataSource.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamingRelation$.apply(StreamingRelation.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamReader.load(DataStreamReader.scala:150)
}
```

In batch processing schema from orc files are derived by default. I was expecting the same here also but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

> By default, Structured Streaming from file based sources requires you to specify the schema, rather than rely on Spark to infer it automatically. This restriction ensures a consistent schema will be used for the streaming query, even in the case of failures. For ad-hoc use cases, you can reenable schema inference by setting spark.sql.streaming.schemaInference to true.

Source: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#schema-inference-and-partition-of-streaming-dataframesdatasets

---

In general I would say that it is a bad idea to rely on schema inference on batch jobs on a productive environment.
First, it is a complex process which will consume compute time.
Second, no matter what kind of processing you will attempt to do on your data, you surely will be assuming some schema. Thus, why don't enforce it from the beginning and fail as soon as the data do not match your assumptions.

Schema inference is great for data exploratory testing on an interactive environment *(like the spark-shell)*, to give you an idea of how the data is composed and what you can do with it.
In such case I doubt you will need streaming, unless you are testing that feature too - if that is the case *(and given the path I am sure it is)* you can use the above setting.

---

Nevertheless, I would suggest using **Datasets** instead of **DataFrames** *(and **Scala** instead of **Java**)* to enforce type-safety, in that way you can create a `case class` to represent your data and derive the schema from it - however, this is only my personal preference and opinion.